# How to move beta users in google play and testflight to the production app

Tags: android, ios, google-play, testflight

We have users on android (through alpha testing on google play) and iOS through testflight. We are almost ready to release our app, how can we move the current pilot users to the production app?

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the version code to a higher version than the alpha version code, and publish an empty set of APKs to the Alpha channel on Google Play, then the Alpha users will all upgrade onto your production APK. I can't answer for iOS.

Comment: In the release management you can create a new release, then just don't add any APKs to it. Then put this release on the Alpha or Beta channel. This step isn't necessary, but tidies things up slightly.